# how to invoke a dynamically named object and its method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation in which the name of my object will be dynamic..

i.e.

```
txtGrantAccess_5.GetValue();
```

i want to know how can I call this dynamically?

e.g.

```
var abcd = 'txtGrantAccess_5';
abcd.GetValue();
```

Please note that txtGrantAccess_5 already exists, please can you also avoid the usage of eval in your answer? I have tried understanding other questions almost similar to this but they are not the same thing...

Comment: Do you mean you will have some global variable with a name you don't know yet?

Comment: If you don't know where the function is stored `eval` is the only option.

Comment: How would you know the name of this dynamically named variable?

Comment: @promanski i have a keyValue so i will know for definite the name will begin with 'txtGrantAccess_'+ keyValue will give me the actual object name that has already been created by server side programming for me toaccess on client side

Comment: @Musa read my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet

```
var abcd = 'txtGrantAccess_5';
this[abcd].GetValue();
```

but be careful with value of "this". If it's in a browser maybe this will help

```
var abcd = 'txtGrantAccess_5';
window[abcd].GetValue();
```

Comment: works like a charm thanks! would this compatible with all browsers? i am talking about the solution with "this"

Comment: @inN0Cent the problem with "this" in JavaScript is that it differs from "this" keyword known in most of other languages. Please google for this this :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get local variables dynamically.  However, if it's a property of an object you can get it with the `[]` syntax.

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = function() {};
obj.foo();
obj['foo'](); // same as above.
```

But in this case a local variable cannot be fetched dynamically at all.

```
var fn = function() {
  var foo = '123';
  // no way to get foo dynamically.
}
```

One exception is global variables.  In the global scope, local variables are created as properties of the window object:

```
// global scope, outside of any function.
var foo = function() {};
window.foo();
window['foo'](); // same as above
```

Just keep in mind that lots of global variables are usually frowned upon, espcially if there is enough that you need to find dynamically like this.  You probably just want a container object to keep these values in, like the first example I posted.

Comment: **-1**, You can get local variables dynamically, just because people don't like eval doesn't mean you can't use it.

Comment: @Connor OP actually said `avoid the usage of eval` in the post

Comment: @Musa i know, this question states nothing about eval but does say that it's not possible to get local variables dynamically.

Comment: Basically, all I'm saying is "You cannot get local variables dynamically." is **false** and "no way to get foo dynamically." is **false**

Comment: @Conor I tend to not think of `eval` because I've been burned by it too many times :)  So yeah, it's _possible_ with `eval`, but sure as hell ain't _advisable._

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var container = {};
var name = 'dynamicName';
container[name] = new MyObject();
container[name].getValue()
```

Comment: the issue is that its not a new object.. its an existing object txtGrantAccess_5 already exists dynamically created by server side programming..